# Delete the element at index N, LinkedList

Tags: java, list, linked-list, nodes

***This is homework***

I have been asked to delete the kth element from a LinkedList. I have also been given its size an `int N`. The question is how do I update the size of my list after deleting the node at position "k"? If there is something wrong with the logic in my code, please mention it.

I don't want the solution just guidance, thanks.

```
int N;               
Node first;         

// delete the kth element (where k is between 0 and N-1 inclusive)
public void delete (int k) {
    if (k < 0 || k >= N)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    Node x = first;
    if( k == 0){
        first = x.next;
        N = N - 1;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < k; i++){
        x = x.next;
        N = N - 1;
    }
    x.next = x.next.next;
    N = N - 2;
}
```

I think I might be doing something wrong with the list size (int N).

Comment: Isn't the size of the list always going to be one less after removing one element?

Comment: Also, is this a singly-linked or doubly-linked list?

Comment: singly-linked list

Comment: Why would you want to manually delete item from list? As far as I know LL has its own delete (or remove I dont remember) method, which will care of any shiftings and relinkings needed.

Comment: The OP is writing their _own_ linked list implementation, not using `java.util.LinkedList`.

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a node, you just need to change the previous `Node`'s `next` to the (new) next node in k and decrement `N` (`N--`) to update the list size.

EDIT

Also pay attention on your for loop you are changing the next of all nodes before node `k`

Answer (score 0):

Consider making two cases: k == 0 and the rest.
The size is given by N so the new size should be N - 1.

```
Node x = first; // What a name
if (k == 0) {
    first = x.next; // Could be first = first.next
    N = N - 1;
    // Are you done here?
}

for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
    x = x.next;
    // Really? N = N - 1;
}
x.next = x.next.next;
// Really? N = N - 2;
N = N - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `list.remove(Object obj)` method defined in LinkedList. To get the object at the k-th element, you can use `list.get(int index)`. Once you find the k-th element, consider breaking or returning to avoid any concurrent modification problems or index-related errors.

Comment: The OP is writing their _own_ linked list implementation, not using `java.util.LinkedList`. Reading the entire question before answering always helps.